# How to manage ThreadPoolTaskExecutor to block some requests

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

We have advanced HR system which has a service calculates employee attendance and leaves it must follow the following if calculating for employee (X, Y, Z) it opens 3 threads and calculate in parallel but if a request to calculate data for employee X again before the previous calculation end it must postpone until previous thread calculating data for employee X finishes.

```
    ScheduleWeekAttendanceBean scheduleWeekAttendanceBean = null;
    ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = employeeThreadPoolExecutorMap.get(employmentBean.id);
    if (threadPoolExecutor == null || threadPoolExecutor.isTerminating() || threadPoolExecutor.isTerminated()) {
        threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(), new RejectedExecutionHandlerImpl());
        employeeThreadPoolExecutorMap.put(employmentBean.id, threadPoolExecutor);

        ThreadPoolTaskExecutorMonitorService threadPoolTaskExecutorMonitorService = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutorMonitorService(threadPoolExecutor, "#" + employmentBean.employeeId);
        Thread thread = new Thread(threadPoolTaskExecutorMonitorService);
        thread.start();
    }

    AttendanceBuilder attendanceBuilder = (AttendanceBuilder) AppContext.getBean("attendanceBuilder");
    attendanceBuilder.initialize(employmentBean, selectedDate);
    Future<ScheduleWeekAttendanceBean> future = threadPoolExecutor.submit(attendanceBuilder);
    scheduleWeekAttendanceBean = future.get();

    if (threadPoolExecutor.getActiveCount() == 0) {
        employeeThreadPoolExecutorMap.remove(employmentBean.id);
        threadPoolExecutor.shutdownNow();
    }

    return scheduleWeekAttendanceBean;
```

What happens here it process them one by one I need to implement this logic but only block if same employee exists in the map.

Answer (score 0):

Creating  separate `ThreadPoolExecutor` for each employee id is overhead. Each `ThreadPoolExecutor` contains a `Thread` which consumes a lot of memory, and this may lead to fatal `OutOfMemoryError`. So I suggest to use `SerialExecutor` instead, which is described in the documentation to the  [java.util.concurrent.Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html). `SerialExecutor` does not contain thread, instead, it uses an external `Executor`. You can create single `Executor` for all `SerialExecutor`s, and tune its configuration (number of threads). Since `SerialExecutor` is small, you can keep all of them in the `employeeThreadPoolExecutorMap` permanently.

Another approach is to use [Actors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) instead of Executors. An actor can be considered as a specialized Executor, designed to process specific tasks (messages). You can use Akka actors, or my [Simple Actor](https://github.com/akaigoro/CodeSamples/blob/master/src/main/java/actor/simpleactor/SimpleActor.java).

Comment: I think actors requires java 1.8 or above in this project we are forced to use java 1.7 cause it is an old project compatible with adobe flex. I will try the SerialExecutor and let you know about results. thanks

Comment: @HusseinAkar no, both Akka and my SimpleActor can be run on java 1.7 and earlier.